# Ravendb memory leak on query

Tags: ravendb

I'm having a hard problem solving an issue with RavenDB.
At my work we have a process to trying to identify potential duplicates in our database on a specified collection (let's call it users collection).

That means, I'm iterating through the collection and for each document there is a query that is trying to find similar entities. So just imagine, it's quite a long task to run.

My problem is, when the task starts running, the memory consumption for RavenDB is going higher and higher, it's literally just growing and growing, and it seems to continue until it reaches the maximum memory of the system.

But it doesn't really makes sense, since I'm only doing query, I'm using one single index and take a default page size when querying (128).

Anybody meet a similar problem like this? I really have no idea what is going on in ravendb. but it seems like a memory leak.

RavenDB version: 3.0.179

Comment: What version of RavenDB are you using ?

Comment: just updated the post with the RavenDB version

Comment: Are you using a single session for the entire process?

Comment: @Iamisti did any of the answers help you?

Comment: @JudahHimango no, not really

Comment: @Iamisti did you try my suggestion about avoiding querying for duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

First, a recommendation: if you don't want duplicates, store them with a well-known ID. For example, suppose you don't want duplicate User objects. You'd store them with an ID that makes them unique:

```
var user = new User() { Email = "foo@bar.com" };
var id = "Users/" + user.Email; // A well-known ID
dbSession.Store(user, id);
```

Then, when you want to check for duplicates, just check against the well known name:

```
public string RegisterNewUser(string email)
{
    // Unlike .Query, the .Load call is ACID and never stale.
    var existingUser = dbSession.Load<User>("Users/" + email);
    if (existingUser != null)
    {
        return "Sorry, that email is already taken.";
    }
}
```

If you follow this pattern, you won't have to worry about running complex queries nor worry about stale indexes.

If this scenario can't work for you for some reason, then we can help diagnose your memory issues. But to diagnose that, we'll need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

When i need to do massive operations on large collections i work following this steps to prevent problems on memory usage:

1. I use [Query Streaming](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/client-api/advanced/unbounded-results) to extract all the ids of the documents that i want to process (**with a dedicated session**)
2. I open a **new session for each id**, i load the document and then i do what i need

Comment: Step 2 is likely overkill. You don't need a new session for each ID. Streaming is fine. If you need to update many objects, consider BulkInsert.

Comment: @JudahHimango maybe it could be, but i neever see any problems on memory usage using this approach